# I am getting the following error when I run sudo apt update

Tags: networking, network-manager

E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code

Comment: Did you try rebooting the computer?

Comment: yes i did but nothing is happning

Comment: Thank you so much , problem is solved with this solution

Comment: can you please tell that why this error occur in my system ?